# How to update json specific key value through client side .net core windows application

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

I have a Restful web service in .net core 5.x which returns JSON data from Postgres, I want to update a specific key value of JSON through client side (windows application) which i want to reflect on Postgres DB also.
I also using .netcore 3.1.3 on client side.

``````
````C#`````
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;
using HttpClientTest_Console.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace HttpClientTest_Console
{
    class Program {
    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    static async Task Main(string[] args){
    try {
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client
 .GetAsync("/api/Employee/GetEmployee");
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }
catch (HttpRequestException e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
  Console.WriteLine("\nMessage : {0}",e.Message);
}
}}}
``````

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you share a piece of code from API side?

Comment: What do you mean by "update a specific key value of JSON"? Do you mean the JSON in the `responseBody` variable? Either parse and update, or deserialize, update and serialize. Then what does "reflect on Postgres DB" mean? Do you mean you want to POST back the updated JSON to the API? Then do so.

Comment: Yes, exactly i want to update the json values back to api (retrieving records from postgre)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be something like this. Below code assumes that you have a data update api on server like "/api/Employee" and some local class to deserialize the data into.

```
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.Deserialize<SomeObj>(responseBody);

data.Field = "New Data";

await client.PostAsync("/api/Employee", JsonConvert.Serialize(data));
```